# How does SQL Server handle failed query to linked server?

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables, linked-server

I have a stored procedure that relies on a query to a linked server.

This stored procedure is roughly structured as follows:

```
-- Create local table var to stop query from needing round trips to linked server
DECLARE @duplicates TABLE (eid NVARCHAR(6))

INSERT INTO @duplicates(eid)
SELECT eid FROM [linked_server].[linked_database].[dbo].[linked_table]
WHERE es = 'String'

-- Update on my server using data from linked server
UPDATE [my_server].[my_database].[dbo].[my_table]

-- Many things, including
[status] = CASE
    WHEN 
        eid IN (
            SELECT eid FROM @duplicates
        ) 
        THEN 'String'
        ELSE es
    END
FROM [my_server].[another_database].[dbo].[view]
-- This view obscures sensitive information and shows only the data that I have permission to see

-- Many other things
```

The query itself is much more complex, but the key idea is building this temporary table from a linked server (because it takes the query 5 minutes to run if I don't, versus 3 seconds if I do).

I've recently had an issue where I ended up with updates to my table that failed to get checked against the linked server for duplicate information.

The logical chain of events is this:

1. Get all of the data from the original view
2. The original view contains maybe 3000 records, of which maybe 30 are
   duplicates of the entity in question, but with 1 field having a
   different value.
3. I then have to grab data from a different server to know which of
   the duplicates is the correct one.
4. When the stored procedure runs, it updates each record.
5. ERROR STEP - when the stored procedure hits a duplicate record, it
   updates `my_table` again - so `es` gets changed multiple times in a row.
6. The temp table was added after the fact when we realized incorrect `es` values were being introduced to `my_table`.
7. 'my_database` does not contain the data needed to determine which is the correct tuple, hence the requirement for the linked server.

As far as I can tell, we had a temporary network interruption or a connection timeout that stopped `my_server` from getting the response back from `linked_server`, and it just passed an empty table to the rest of the procedure.

So, my question is - how can I guard against this happening?

I can't just check if the table is empty, because it could legitimately be empty.  I need to definitively know if that initial `SELECT` from `linked_server` failed, if it timed out, or if it intentionally returned nothing.

Comment: Can you elaborate on *I've recently had an issue where I ended up with updates to my table that failed to get checked against the linked server for duplicate information.*, If the table was empty, how did bad updates happen? You said it could legitimately be empty, so how would this affect the update vs a time out? Side note, I'd use a temp table instead of a table variable for this.

Comment: I second @scsimon 's suggestion.

Comment: Is the linked server set up with `connection timeout = 0` and `query timeout = 0`? You might want to set that if it isn't.

Comment: I would expect the timeout to raise an error which caused the whole transaction to fail... LEVEL 16... so are you sure that this happened?

Comment: @scsimon I added more context to the original question to help figure it out.

Comment: @scsimon, and to your second question... I am not 100% sure, honestly, but maybe 97%.  I know that the procedure executed on time last night.  I know that it updated a number of rows in `my_table`.  And it changed itself back the next time it executed, an hour later.  This application and stored proc have not been touched in 3 months, so it wasn't a code-level change.  The source on `linked_server` recorded no changes at that time.  The only way I see that that result could have happened is if the variable table failed to fill, but the rest of the stored proc ran as normal.

Comment: Where are you getting the data from the original view in your code? If i'm reading this correctly, the issue is your UPDATE didn't choose the right values because you didn't bounce that off a view?

Comment: So... part of the problem here is that I am trying to use code to plug serious gaps in a business process.  The view has 99% correct info, but 1% legitimately wrong data.  I start with that view, but then I have to double-check some of the tuples that come back from it.  The trip to the linked server is to get the list of tuples, by `eid`, which I need to double-check.

Comment: And your view is on another server it seems.  I still don't see how the time out didn't raise an error. Did you see this in the error log?

Comment: Yes, the view is on another server.  That's kinda where I am at.  I don't understand how this procedure finished running and made those updates.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197994/discussion-between-scsimon-and-bluemoon6790).

Answer (score -1):

without knowing the definition of the table you're querying you could get into an issue where your data is to long and you get a truncation error on your table.

Better make sure and substring it...

```
DECLARE @duplicates TABLE (eid NVARCHAR(6))

INSERT INTO @duplicates(eid)
SELECT SUBSTRING(eid,1,6) FROM [linked_server].[linked_database].[dbo].[linked_table]
WHERE es = 'String'

-- Update on my server using data from linked server
UPDATE [my_server].[my_database].[dbo].[my_table]

-- Many things, including
[status] = CASE
    WHEN 
        eid IN (
            SELECT eid FROM @duplicates
        ) 
        THEN 'String'
        ELSE es
    END
FROM [my_server].[another_database].[dbo].[view]
```

I had a similar problem where I needed to move data between servers, could not use a network connection so I ended up doing BCP out and BCP in. This is fast, clean and takes away the complexity of user authentication, drivers, trust domains. also it's repeatable and can be used for incremental loading.

Comment: Noted, but I don't think that would be the root of the problem here.  The records that ended up changed would have returned a list of about 30 rows of 6 characters.